# Can't Install LibreOffice due to Dependency Problem

Tags: linux-mint, dependencies, libreoffice

I ran

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist upgrade
```

and it basically removed my LibreOffice installation. Now when I try to install it again using

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

it gave me dependency problems. So I executed

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
```

then I tried to install but same problem.
I am getting this error

```
gameranand@serenity ~ $ sudo apt-get -f install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.2.0~rc1-0ubuntu1~xenial1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this. I really need the solution because I use Libreoffice on daily basis.

Comment: Perhaps try installing with `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`?

Comment: Tried that too...No avail.

Comment: Try to install each of the packages on that list starting with `apt-get install libreoffice-base`.  The `libreoffice` package is just a bundle of packages, if the bundle is screwed (it might be) you can still e possible to install the packages one by one.

Comment: `dist upgrade` is dangerous in `mint`, since it uses `ubuntu` repos but not all of them and it does not have all the `ubuntu` extras either.

Comment: Tried installing packages one by one. Same problem.

Yeah Now I know dist-upgrade is dangerous. Won't run it again if it tries to screw up my installations. But in the meantime please give me the solution for this problem.

Comment: Maybe try find held packages by `sudo apt-mark showhold`, then remove them with `sudo apt-mark unhold <name>`, then remove libreoffice and reinstall.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't help. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Ubuntu (Trusty > Xenial) and Linux Mint (Rosa > Sarah) have just had a distribution update, this might have caused the dependence problems. For me, on Mint Rosa 17.3, Libreoffice works fine and doesn't show an available update (installed version `1:5.0.3~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty2`). If you have very recently updated to Mint 18 I suggest posting this issue on the Linux Mint forums.

Otherwise try installing an older version of Libreoffice (not based on Ubuntu `xenial`, but Ubuntu `trusty`). See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get

Or, if you're feeling lucky, a complete rollback from the `dist upgrade`: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=15750. I have never tried this myself, so I don't know how well that will work.

Remember to always use `apt-get upgrade` in the future :).

Comment: Thanks. I knew something was the problem, I just didn't know what.

I just uninstalled the Libre and reinstalled from the site. I needed the features of Libre 5.